# floor while calculating between two dates is giving 0 in Oracle

Tags: oracle, datetime

I have two dates by which I am calculating no of years/months. For below 2 dates I am getting output as `0` as it should return `0.4` months.

Here is my query

```
select floor((months_between(to_date('2022-07-01T00:00:00+05:30'), to_date('2022-01-11T00:00:00+05:30', 'dd-mm-yy'))) /12)
```

from dual;

Please suggest what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Nad, your SQL does not run at all, and does not gives an error. Even if it did, did you lookup what [FLOOR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/FLOOR.html#GUID-67F61AC7-C097-4397-A122-213157BF584F) does? if you want 0.4 then remove the FLOOR

Comment: @gsalem: this is the value it should pass. `select floor((months_between(CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2022-07-01T00:00:00+05:30','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM') AS DATE), 
CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2022-01-11T00:00:00+05:30','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM') AS DATE))) /12)
from dual;` now how I will get it 0.4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`floor` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/FLOOR.html):

> returns the largest integer equal to or less than n

so there is no way it can return 0.4. The `ceil` function is the similar. Neither takes an argument allowing retention of decimal places. And you don't want to `round` it, as in your example that would give 0.5, not 0.4.

Fortunately you can use [`trunc`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRUNC-number.html#GUID-911AE7FE-E04A-471D-8B0E-9C50EBEFE07D), which does have a decimal-place argument:

> The `TRUNC (number)` function returns *n1* truncated to *n2* decimal places.

So you want `trunc(<difference between dates>, 1)` to get retain 1 decimal place.

```
select trunc (
  months_between(
    CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2022-07-01T00:00:00+05:30','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM') AS DATE), 
    CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2022-01-11T00:00:00+05:30','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM') AS DATE)
  ) / 12
  , 1
) as result
from dual;

.4
```

---

Here `trunc` behaves essentially as you would want `floor(n1, n2)` to if that existed; there is no equivalent for `ceil`, but [you can work around that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48305531/266304). The same method can be applied here too, but isn't needed; I've included it in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=84e8bf046aa3e1fe427972605b2456fa) for fun.

Answer (score 1):

You want:

- to use `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` and not `TO_DATE`
- to use a format model that matches the timestamp format such as `YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZD`
- to use `FLOOR` before dividing by 12 if you want to find the number of full months.

```sql
select FLOOR(
         MONTHS_BETWEEN(
           to_timestamp_tz('2022-07-01T00:00:00+05:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZD'),
           to_timestamp_tz('2022-01-11T00:00:00+05:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZD')
         )
       ) / 12 AS full_months_diff
from   dual;
```

Which outputs:

> | FULL_MONTHS_DIFF |
> | --- |
> | .4166666666666666666666666666666666666667 |

Alternatively, you could use the difference between the timestamps as an `INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH` data type:

```sql
select EXTRACT(
         YEAR FROM
         ( to_timestamp_tz('2022-07-01T00:00:00+05:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZD')
         - to_timestamp_tz('2022-01-11T00:00:00+05:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZD')
         ) YEAR TO MONTH
       ) AS years,
       EXTRACT(
         MONTH FROM
         (to_timestamp_tz('2022-07-01T00:00:00+05:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZD')
         - to_timestamp_tz('2022-01-11T00:00:00+05:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZD')
         ) YEAR TO MONTH
       ) AS months
from   dual;
```

> | YEARS | MONTHS |
> | --- | --- |
> | 0 | 6 |

Which rounds up the number of months.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1d50aa7a9833d5710e8fc9983c31c6db)*